# How to delete tenants in wso2 AS 5.3.0

Tags: wso2

(1st question in Stackoverflow, be gentle; yes i searched)

I'm using wso2 AS 5.3.0.
How can i delete a tenant?

Not in the admin UI. Thats in the docs. OK.
But it should be possible trough the admin services. With SOAPUI for example.

Admin services need to be un-hidden in carbon.xml first, which i did.

Now it exposes an admin service that has a delete function, 
(https://localhost:9443/services/TenantMgtAdminService?wsdl)
but it does not work. (Exception)

I read on stackoverflow that this is normal, but another admin service works (some people seem to use it with succes)
https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteTenantManagerService?wsdl
This one however seems not to be installed with AS 5.3.0
Also there is no documentation around on what plugin or product it is part of or how to install it.

The whole story seems sketchy to me.
Am i missing something completely?

Comment: Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Or NOT having this problem: can you delete tenants? how?